# SQL set two variables from subquery

Tags: sql-server

In my sql query I need to two local variables to do some control flow. Those two variables are `id` and `name`. I currently have this:

```sql
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20)
SET @id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM users WHERE users.username = @username);
SET @name = (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM users WHERE users.username = @username);
...
```

But it seems unperformant running the subquery twice. Is there a way I can combine them so that it can destructure the column into the two variables? I was thinking something like?

```
SET @id, @name = (SELECT TOP 1 id, name FROM users WHERE users.username = @username);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using TOP 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT @id = id, @name = name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.username = @username
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @id = id, @name = name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.username = @username
```

**Note:-**

SET will accept and assign a scalar (single) value from a query. While SELECT could accept multiple returned values.

If you are using this above Query...it will pick up the last value of table

Here is Greate Article For this SET v/s Select

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1888/when-to-use-set-vs-select-when-assigning-values-to-variables-in-sql-server/